# можно ли использовать react hook в компоненте высшего порядка(HOC)?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

хочу реализовать проверку авторизован пользователь или нет что бы не дублировать код надо использовать именно компоненты высшего порядка до этого с ними я не работал поэтому не получается решить проблему с использованием своего хука useAuth() который проверяет введенный пароль и почту и отрисовывает компонент если все верно

```
import { useAuth } from "hooks/useAuth";
import React from "react";

export const AuthUser = (Component) => {
  const { isAuth } = useAuth();

  const myComponent = () => {
    return isAuth ? <Component /> : <div>adadasdasdasd</div>;
  };

  return myComponent;
};
```

хотел реализовать что то подобное но реакт ругается на то что я использую хук

выкидывая ошибку: `Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:`

Comment: Хуки можно использовать только в компонентах. Что в вашем коде является компонентом? Подсказка: AuthUser компонентом не является...

Comment: только что исправил это ошибку спасибо